# CORS requesting origin not matches resource's allowed origin

Tags: asp.net, angular, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, cors

`api program.cs` file:

```
using _5_LayeredArchitecture.Extensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Repositories.EfCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//cors
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7211").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Presentation.AssemblyReference).Assembly) 
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(); 
    
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddDebug();

builder.Services.ConfigureSqlContext(builder.Configuration); 
builder.Services.ConfigureRepositoryManager(); 
builder.Services.ConfigureServiceManager();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:7211");
    await next();
});
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`app.components.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'a';
  buildings: any[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}


getData() {
  this.http.get<any[]>('https://localhost:7211/api/[Building]').subscribe(
    (response) => {
      this.building = response;
      console.log(this.building);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error)
  );
}
}
```

> Error: A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request.
>
> To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values.
>
> Note that if an opaque response is sufficient, the request's mode can be set to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled; that way CORS headers are not required but the response content is inaccessible (opaque).
>
> Request   Status  Preflight Request (if problematic)  Header  Problem Invalid Value (if available)
> [Building]   blocked     Access-Control-Allow-Origin Missing Header

I'm developing an application where I use asp.net web api, docker and postgrsql on the backend and angular on the frontend. But I can't view my data on the client.

> HttpErrorResponse
>
> ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
> headers:
> HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
> message:
> "Http failure response for https://localhost:7211/api/[Building]: 0 Unknown Error"
> name:
> "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok:
> false
> status: 0
> statusText: "Unknown Error"
> url: "https://localhost:7211/api/[Building]"

Comment: I'm confused... Your question only mentions one Web origin: `https://localhost:7211`. What are the respective Web origins of your client and server? Your server's CORS configuration should allow your client's Web origin, not your server's.